# SMTP E-Mails won't send from Flask application (500)

Tags: html, flask, bootstrap-5, flask-mail

I am building a website with Python and Flask and I built a Contact Form Modal. The Modal does open up and i can fill it (thanks to the community <3), but i get 500 Internal Server Error once i submit.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory, request
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
from config import sender_mail_username, sender_mail_password, recipient_mail_username

app = Flask(__name__)

mail = Mail(app)

app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] = "smtp.gmail.com"
app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 465
app.config["MAIL_USE_TLS"] = False
app.config["MAIL_USE_SSL"] = True
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = sender_mail_username
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = sender_mail_password


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def contact():
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.form.get("email")
        subject = request.form.get("subject")
        message = request.form.get("message")

        msg = Message(sender=sender_mail_username, recipients=recipient_mail_username,
                      subject="UNIFINITY Contact Form submission", body=f"Email {email}\nSubject: {subject}"
                                                                        f"\n\n{message}")
        mail.send(msg)
    return render_template("sent.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run()
```

I do use the method "POST"

```
<form name="contact" role="form" method="POST">
```

And the send-button type is on submit

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Send</button>
```

EDIT: This is the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jules/Documents/IT/Pycharm/UNIFINITY Webpage/webpage.py", line 35, in contact
    mail.send(msg)
  File "/Users/Jules/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 491, in send
    with self.connect() as connection:
  File "/Users/Jules/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 144, in __enter__
    self.host = self.configure_host()
  File "/Users/Jules/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 158, in configure_host
    host = smtplib.SMTP(self.mail.server, self.mail.port)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 843, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 831, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
[2023-12-05 09:31:58,550] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 870, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 889, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1161, in make_response
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function for 'contact' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Dec/2023 09:31:58] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I've tried the SMTP Test through https://www.gmass.co/smtp-test and I can send e-mails. So i figure it must be an coding mistake somewhere. As seen on the flask_mail documentation i figured the sender= parameter has to be a list, is that correct?

Thank you for your inputs <3

Comment: Which part fails? if you were to put a print between each in the "POST" part of that route, which line does the code get to before it fails?

Comment: If you can share the stack trace with us it would help us debug the issue with you

Comment: Thank you for your answers. 
@Harrison The thing is the code doesn't fail, it runs correctly. I can open up the contact form, and fill it out, as soon as i hit submit, the site crashes and i get a 500 Internal Server Error
@ mayankmehtani I must admit im fairly new to programming, first big project. I've just done my googles and if i understand right i should try to get a stack trace with the traceback.print_exc() function, is that right? How do i do that?

Comment: @mayankmehtani Wow id didn't see there was a Traceback..... Just added it to the main post

Comment: It's been a while but I believe the route path should be different for `home` (`"/"`) and `contact` (maybe `"/contact"`), and your `form` element would post to the `contact` route,  with `action="/contact"`,  I assume that `sent.html` exists?

Comment: i eliminated `sent.html` (this one wasn't working anyways, will add it again later on) and changed the route to `/contact` and action to `action="/contact"` still doesn't work.. Now once i hit Send on the form, the page opens on /contact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was already dealt with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881929/flask-mail-gmail-connection-refused)

`mail = Mail(app)` should come after

```
app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] = "smtp.gmail.com"
app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 465
app.config["MAIL_USE_TLS"] = False
app.config["MAIL_USE_SSL"] = True
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = sender_mail_username
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = sender_mail_password
```